# $.getJSON on external API returns "500 internal server error" ... sometimes

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, http-status-code-500

This is a cross domain call. I use `&callback=?` to make it work, the response is JSON. I am using this information to print traffic messages on a google map.

This is working alright, but some times (50% almost) I get an error

> 500 internal server error

from the server.

Loading the API link in the browser never fails, so what bothers me is that this map is not working on every other refresh.

I have tried a lot of different methods for calling the api, including the AJAX function with jsonp format, but nothing seems to work.

Really annoying that this only happens from time to time.

Is there something I am missing, or is JS not the best option for getting a JSON cross domain?

```
$.getJSON( "http://sencored.com/api/external/feed?feed=traffic&callback=?", function( data ) {

        list = data.events.list;
        dispplayOnMap();
});
```

Comment: is your web on https? if it is then use https in API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested; I ended up using PHP for this. Same URL, no errors.

```
public static function getJSON($url) {
    try {
        $json_feed = file_get_contents($url);
        return $json_feed;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return "error: " . $e;
    }
}
```